# copy content of text file and inserting into database table where a given column is equal to the title of te text file

Tags: php, mysql, file

I have a folder with text files. the text files were created when user submit form data and were named based on the user input of a particular column, I would like to use these file contents to update one table in a database using a where clause with two conditions, first where the email of user correspond to the `email` column in the table, and second where the file title correspond to `title` column in the table. For each row, I would like to have the the content of the file that it's title correspond saved in `seen` column.

I'm using the below code but it's not working

```
$size = "";

$dir = "counters/ads";

if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
    if($file == '.' || $file == '..') continue;

    $myFile = "$dir/$file";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');

    $size = filesize($myFile);
    if ($size > 0) {
    $content = fread($fh, $size);

    $name = $file;

    }
    $target = $row2['target'];
    $progress = ($content/$target)*100;
    // Check connection     
    $result3=mysqli_query($db_handle,"UPDATE advert SET seen='$content', progress='$progress', counter='$name' WHERE email='".$email."' && title='".$title."'");


    fclose($fh);
}
closedir($handle);
}
```

However when I removed the title where condition, the query update the table by inserting  `$name` into `counter` column, but it's not updating `$content` into `seen` column

Please any idea on how I can go about it

Comment: Where/how are `$email` and `$title` assigned as and their values? Your `WHERE` clause is dependent on those variables. Same for `$file`.

Comment: `$email` is session variable assigned as `$email = $_SESSION['email'];` which hold the email that user login with, and `$title` hold the file name `$title = $file`

Comment: Make sure all variables including session arrays contain value. Use `var_dump();` for them and use error reporting as I stated in my answer. Those tools will help you to debug, should there be errors anywhere. Also make sure the file is reachable.

Comment: @Fred did that, the `$title` variable hold only the last file in the folder, and the files are reachable too

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is the semi-colon just before the `WHERE` clause:

```
counter='$name';
```

It terminates the process. You need to remove it.

Since the semi-colon is a perfectly valid character in PHP, it would not have thrown an error for it.

It's what's called an "end of statement" character.

Reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php

> *As in C or Perl, PHP requires instructions to be terminated with a semicolon at the end of each statement. The closing tag of a block of PHP code automatically implies a semicolon; you do not need to have a semicolon **terminating** the last line of a PHP block. The closing tag for the block will include the immediately trailing newline if one is present."*

It's also best to check for errors using PHP's error reporting and `mysqli_error()` on the query, just in case.

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: Thanks Fred, sorry the semicolon is not in my code, it's a typo while editing the code here, but I removed the semicolon and modified the question

Comment: @ImtaazAbdollahBenYusouf Welcome. Check for errors on the query, I added a few error checking links near the bottom of my answer. Maybe something MySQL is complaining about in the background.

Comment: @ImtaazAbdollahBenYusouf Thing is though; I based myself on your original post http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/43281887/1 and you overwrote it in an edit http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/43281887/2 without marking it as an edit anywhere. I stand to get downvoted for it. You should either rollback to the original, or rollback and edit it saying somewhere under the original post that you made a mistake.

Comment: Edited and explained that i removed the semicolon as you answered